# Richtextbox wpf binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, richtextbox

To do DataBinding of the `Document` in a WPF `RichtextBox`, I saw 2 solutions so far, which are to derive from the `RichtextBox` and add a `DependencyProperty`, and also the solution with a "proxy".

Neither the first or the second are satisfactory. Does somebody know another solution, or instead, a commercial RTF control which is capable of **DataBinding**? The normal `TextBox` is not an alternative, since we need text formatting.

Any idea?

Comment: The answer to be **rewarded**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909764/480982

Answer (score 118, accepted):

There is a much easier way!

You can easily create an attached `DocumentXaml` (or `DocumentRTF`) property which will allow you to bind the `RichTextBox`'s document. It is used like this, where `Autobiography` is a string property in your data model:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" />
<RichTextBox local:RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml="{Binding Autobiography}" />
```

Voila!  Fully bindable `RichTextBox` data!

The implementation of this property is quite simple: When the property is set, load the XAML (or RTF) into a new `FlowDocument`. When the `FlowDocument` changes, update the property value.

This code should do the trick:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
public class RichTextBoxHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static string GetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(DocumentXamlProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DocumentXamlProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentXamlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DocumentXaml",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(RichTextBoxHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
                {
                    var richTextBox = (RichTextBox)obj;

                    // Parse the XAML to a document (or use XamlReader.Parse())
                    var xaml = GetDocumentXaml(richTextBox);
                    var doc = new FlowDocument();
                    var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

                    range.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xaml)),
                          DataFormats.Xaml);

                    // Set the document
                    richTextBox.Document = doc;

                    // When the document changes update the source
                    range.Changed += (obj2, e2) =>
                    {
                        if (richTextBox.Document == doc)
                        {
                            MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
                            range.Save(buffer, DataFormats.Xaml);
                            SetDocumentXaml(richTextBox,
                                Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray()));
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
}
```

The same code could be used for TextFormats.RTF or TextFormats.XamlPackage. For XamlPackage you would have a property of type `byte[]` instead of `string`.

The XamlPackage format has several advantages over plain XAML, especially the ability to include resources such as images, and it is more flexible and easier to work with than RTF.

It is hard to believe this question sat for 15 months without anyone pointing out the easy way to do this.

Comment: If you have multiple RichTextBoxes on the same window, this solution will not work.

Comment: @Kelly, use DataFormats.Rtf, this can solve multiple richtextboxes issue.

Comment: Two-way isn't working for me (using Rtf). The `range.Changed` event is never getting called.

Comment: @FabianBigler - Hi - in case anybody has the same problem - you need to add the xmlns:local declaration to your xaml file that will point to the namespace where this is available

Comment: can someone give an example of the value of Autobiography?

Comment: @longlostbro, Here it is an example of the value:
https://gist.github.com/bakulev/614a665241cc4fd69409e1ab3e03a9ba

Comment: @AntonBakulev Thanks!

Comment: The backing string (`Autobiography`) in the VM must be a FlowDocument in xml format. For example: `<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph Foreground="Red"><Bold>Hello</Bold></Paragraph></FlowDocument>`

Answer (score 27):

I know this is an old post, but check out the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit).  It has a RichTextBox that supports what you are tryign to do.

Comment: RichTextBox from Extended WPF Toolkit is really slow I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix you do realize this is just the WPF RichTextBox with an extra property on it right?

Comment: (jump ahead to 2017...) the wpf toolkits RichTextBox works with rich text or plain text right out of the box. It also seems a lot faster than using the helper method below (which throws an exception if you just copy/paste it)

Comment: Their free license is for non-commercial use only. :/

Answer (score 19):

I can give you an ok solution and you can go with it, but before I do I'm going to try to explain why Document is *not* a `DependencyProperty` to begin with.

During the lifetime of a `RichTextBox` control, the `Document` property generally doesn't change. The `RichTextBox` is initialized with a `FlowDocument`. That document is displayed, can be edited and mangled in many ways, but the underlying value of the `Document` property remains that one instance of the `FlowDocument`. Therefore, there is really no reason it should be a `DependencyProperty`, ie, Bindable. If you have multiple locations that reference this `FlowDocument`, you only need the reference once. Since it is the same instance everywhere, the changes will be accessible to everyone.

I don't think `FlowDocument` supports document change notifications, though I am not sure.

That being said, here's a solution. Before you start, since `RichTextBox` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and Document is not a `DependencyProperty`, we have no notifications when the `RichTextBox`'s Document property changes, so the binding can only be OneWay.

Create a class that will provide the `FlowDocument`. Binding requires the existence of a `DependencyProperty`, so this class inherits from `DependencyObject`.

```
class HasDocument : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Document", 
                                    typeof(FlowDocument), 
                                    typeof(HasDocument), 
                                    new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(DocumentChanged)));

    private static void DocumentChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Document has changed");
    }

    public FlowDocument Document
    {
        get { return GetValue(DocumentProperty) as FlowDocument; }
        set { SetValue(DocumentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Create a `Window` with a rich text box in XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="samples.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Flow Document Binding" Height="300" Width="300"
    >
    <Grid>
      <RichTextBox Name="richTextBox" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Give the `Window` a field of type `HasDocument`.

```
HasDocument hasDocument;
```

Window constructor should create the binding.

```
hasDocument = new HasDocument();

InitializeComponent();

Binding b = new Binding("Document");
b.Source = richTextBox;
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(hasDocument, HasDocument.DocumentProperty, b);
```

If you want to be able to declare the binding in XAML, you would have to make your `HasDocument` class derive from `FrameworkElement` so that it can be inserted into the logical tree.

Now, if you were to change the `Document` property on `HasDocument`, the rich text box's `Document` will also change.

```
FlowDocument d = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph g = new Paragraph();
Run a = new Run();
a.Text = "I showed this using a binding";
g.Inlines.Add(a);
d.Blocks.Add(g);

hasDocument.Document = d;
```

Comment: +1 for the good answer, but one quibble: There is a reason to make the Document property a dependency property--to facilitate using the control with the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Fair point, but I disagree; just because MVVM is used widely in WPF apps doesn't mean that WPF's API should change just to accomodate it. We work around it in whatever way we can. This is one solution. We may also simply choose to encapsulate our Rich Text Box in a user control and have a dependency property defined on the UserControl.

Answer (score 19):

I have tuned up previous code a little bit.
First of all range.Changed hasn't work for me.
After I changed range.Changed to richTextBox.TextChanged it turns out that TextChanged event handler can invoke SetDocumentXaml recursively, so I've provided protection against it. I also used XamlReader/XamlWriter instead of TextRange.

```
public class RichTextBoxHelper : DependencyObject
{
    private static HashSet<Thread> _recursionProtection = new HashSet<Thread>();

    public static string GetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(DocumentXamlProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        _recursionProtection.Add(Thread.CurrentThread);
        obj.SetValue(DocumentXamlProperty, value);
        _recursionProtection.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentXamlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DocumentXaml", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(RichTextBoxHelper), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            "", 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            (obj, e) => {
                if (_recursionProtection.Contains(Thread.CurrentThread))
                    return;

                var richTextBox = (RichTextBox)obj;

                // Parse the XAML to a document (or use XamlReader.Parse())

                try
                {
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetDocumentXaml(richTextBox)));
                    var doc = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(stream);

                    // Set the document
                    richTextBox.Document = doc;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    richTextBox.Document = new FlowDocument();
                }

                // When the document changes update the source
                richTextBox.TextChanged += (obj2, e2) =>
                {
                    RichTextBox richTextBox2 = obj2 as RichTextBox;
                    if (richTextBox2 != null)
                    {
                        SetDocumentXaml(richTextBox, XamlWriter.Save(richTextBox2.Document));
                    }
                };
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lolo!  I was having problems with the original class, too.  This fixed it for me.  Huge time saver!

Comment: I have found a small problem with this solution.  It is possible to have the hook for TextChanged get set multiple times if the view is not closed and recreated between calls.  I am creating a single view once and loading via a list selection.  To fix this, I created a more typical method for hooking the TextChanged event.  Then I simply unhook the method before hooking it.  This ensures it is only hooked once.  No more memory leak (and no more slow running code).

Comment: This is a nice working solution, how ever, in my experience it's not working with multiple controls see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909764/3001007).

Comment: This is great, thanks. Doesn't work if you want to set the binding programmatically though, I assume because the thread setting the binding is different than that which sets via XAML. So I had to add a SetDocumentXamlFirst method, which doesn't use the recursion protection and would only be called manually when you first want to set the value.

Comment: The backing string in the VM must be a FlowDocument in xml format else the Load will fail. For example: `<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph Foreground="Red"><Bold>Hello</Bold></Paragraph></FlowDocument>`

Answer (score 15):

```
 <RichTextBox>
     <FlowDocument PageHeight="180">
         <Paragraph>
             <Run Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
          </Paragraph>
     </FlowDocument>
 </RichTextBox>
```

This seems to be the easiest way by far and isn't displayed in any of these answers.

In the view model just have the `Text` variable.

Comment: In my case this solution shows the text of the Text property in the View Model in vertical, that is, one for in each row.

Comment: It's all I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: How is this solution different from a regular TextBox bound to the Text property? It defeats the purpose of a rich text box supporting formatting that is effectively switched off using this code.

Comment: This was perfect for me. The simpler the better!

Comment: This doesn't allow adding multiple paragraphs or multiple runs. The whole reason to use a rich text box is to get to those features.

Comment: Also this answer appeared 3 years earlier here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236465

Answer (score 10):

Create a UserControl which has a RichTextBox named RTB. Now add the following dependency property:

```
    public FlowDocument Document
    {
        get { return (FlowDocument)GetValue(DocumentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DocumentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Document", typeof(FlowDocument), typeof(RichTextBoxControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnDocumentChanged));

    private static void OnDocumentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBoxControl control = (RichTextBoxControl) d;
        FlowDocument document = e.NewValue as FlowDocument;
        if (document  == null)
        {
            control.RTB.Document = new FlowDocument(); //Document is not amused by null :)
        }
        else
        {
            control.RTB.Document = document;
        }
    }
```

This solution is probably that "proxy" solution you saw somewhere.. However.. RichTextBox simply does not have Document as DependencyProperty... So you have to do this in another way...

HTH

Comment: In the last line you use "document" which throws an error in my code. It has to be an instance of Document because of the static method. But instance of what? I am setting the document I get through the DependencyProperty, the "Document". Removing the "static" breaks the last argument of the DependencyProperty. So here I'm stuck. The Helper-class from above doesn't show any text either :(

Answer (score 5):

Most of my needs were satisfied by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989277/3001007 by [krzysztof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360374/krzysztof). But one issue with that code (i faced was), the binding won't work with multiple controls. So I changed `_recursionProtection` with a `Guid` based implementation. So it's working for Multiple controls in same window as well.

```
 public class RichTextBoxHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        private static List<Guid> _recursionProtection = new List<Guid>();

        public static string GetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(DocumentXamlProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            var fw1 = (FrameworkElement)obj;
            if (fw1.Tag == null || (Guid)fw1.Tag == Guid.Empty)
                fw1.Tag = Guid.NewGuid();
            _recursionProtection.Add((Guid)fw1.Tag);
            obj.SetValue(DocumentXamlProperty, value);
            _recursionProtection.Remove((Guid)fw1.Tag);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentXamlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DocumentXaml",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(RichTextBoxHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                "",
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                (obj, e) =>
                {
                    var richTextBox = (RichTextBox)obj;
                    if (richTextBox.Tag != null && _recursionProtection.Contains((Guid)richTextBox.Tag))
                        return;


                    // Parse the XAML to a document (or use XamlReader.Parse())

                    try
                    {
                        string docXaml = GetDocumentXaml(richTextBox);
                        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(docXaml));
                        FlowDocument doc;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(docXaml))
                        {
                            doc = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(stream);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            doc = new FlowDocument();
                        }

                        // Set the document
                        richTextBox.Document = doc;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        richTextBox.Document = new FlowDocument();
                    }

                    // When the document changes update the source
                    richTextBox.TextChanged += (obj2, e2) =>
                        {
                            RichTextBox richTextBox2 = obj2 as RichTextBox;
                            if (richTextBox2 != null)
                            {
                                SetDocumentXaml(richTextBox, XamlWriter.Save(richTextBox2.Document));
                            }
                        };
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

For completeness sake, let me add few more lines from original answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641774/3001007 by [ray-burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199245/ray-burns). This is how to use the helper.

```
<RichTextBox local:RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml="{Binding Autobiography}" />
```

Comment: After trying 2 highly upvoted suggestions, this finally worked for us.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution based on Ray Burns answer with DataBinding and conversion of a XAML-string to a RichTextBox-Document:

ViewModel

```
    TestText = @"<FlowDocument xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""><Paragraph><Bold>Hello World!</Bold></Paragraph></FlowDocument>";
```

View

```
<RichTextBox local:RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml="{Binding TestText}"/>
```

RichTextBoxHelper

```
public class RichTextBoxHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static string GetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj) { return (string) obj.GetValue(DocumentXamlProperty); }

    public static void SetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj,
                                       string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DocumentXamlProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentXamlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
    (
        "DocumentXaml",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(RichTextBoxHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
        {
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            PropertyChangedCallback = (obj,
                                       e) =>
            {
                var    richTextBox = (RichTextBox) obj;
                var    xaml        = GetDocumentXaml(richTextBox);
                Stream sm          = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xaml));
                richTextBox.Document = (FlowDocument) XamlReader.Load(sm);
                sm.Close();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VB.Net version of Lolo's answer:

```
Public Class RichTextBoxHelper
Inherits DependencyObject

Private Shared _recursionProtection As New HashSet(Of System.Threading.Thread)()

Public Shared Function GetDocumentXaml(ByVal depObj As DependencyObject) As String
    Return DirectCast(depObj.GetValue(DocumentXamlProperty), String)
End Function

Public Shared Sub SetDocumentXaml(ByVal depObj As DependencyObject, ByVal value As String)
    _recursionProtection.Add(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
    depObj.SetValue(DocumentXamlProperty, value)
    _recursionProtection.Remove(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly DocumentXamlProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DocumentXaml", GetType(String), GetType(RichTextBoxHelper), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender Or FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, Sub(depObj, e)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    RegisterIt(depObj, e)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                End Sub))

Private Shared Sub RegisterIt(ByVal depObj As System.Windows.DependencyObject, ByVal e As System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    If _recursionProtection.Contains(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread) Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim rtb As RichTextBox = DirectCast(depObj, RichTextBox)
    Try
        rtb.Document = Markup.XamlReader.Parse(GetDocumentXaml(rtb))
    Catch
        rtb.Document = New FlowDocument()
    End Try
    ' When the document changes update the source
    AddHandler rtb.TextChanged, AddressOf TextChanged
End Sub

Private Shared Sub TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TextChangedEventArgs)
    Dim rtb As RichTextBox = TryCast(sender, RichTextBox)
    If rtb IsNot Nothing Then
        SetDocumentXaml(sender, Markup.XamlWriter.Save(rtb.Document))
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

This VB.Net version works for my situation. I removed thread collection semaphore, instead using RemoveHandler and AddHandler. Also, since a FlowDocument can only be bound to one RichTextBox at a time, I put in a check that the RichTextBox's IsLoaded=True. Let's begin with how I used the class in a MVVM app which uses ResourceDictionary instead of Window.

```vb
    ' Loaded and Unloaded events seems to be the only way to initialize a control created from a Resource Dictionary
' Loading document here because Loaded is the last available event to create a document
Private Sub Rtb_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    ' only good place to initialize RichTextBox.Document with DependencyProperty
    Dim rtb As RichTextBox = DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox)
    Try
        rtb.Document = RichTextBoxHelper.GetDocumentXaml(rtb)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("Rtb_Loaded: Message:" & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

' Loaded and Unloaded events seems to be the only way to initialize a control created from a Resource Dictionary
' Free document being held by RichTextBox.Document by assigning New FlowDocument to RichTextBox.Document. Otherwise we'll see an of "Document belongs to another RichTextBox"
Private Sub Rtb_Unloaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim rtb As RichTextBox = DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox)
    Dim fd As New FlowDocument
    RichTextBoxHelper.SetDocumentXaml(rtb, fd)
    Try
        rtb.Document = fd
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("PoemDocument.PoemDocumentView.PoemRtb_Unloaded: Message:" & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Class RichTextBoxHelper
    Inherits DependencyObject

    Public Shared Function GetDocumentXaml(ByVal depObj As DependencyObject) As FlowDocument
        Return depObj.GetValue(DocumentXamlProperty)
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetDocumentXaml(ByVal depObj As DependencyObject, ByVal value As FlowDocument)
        depObj.SetValue(DocumentXamlProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly DocumentXamlProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DocumentXaml", GetType(FlowDocument), GetType(RichTextBoxHelper), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender Or FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, Sub(depObj, e)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   RegisterIt(depObj, e)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               End Sub))


    Private Shared Sub RegisterIt(ByVal depObj As System.Windows.DependencyObject, ByVal e As System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim rtb As RichTextBox = DirectCast(depObj, RichTextBox)
        If rtb.IsLoaded Then
            RemoveHandler rtb.TextChanged, AddressOf TextChanged
            Try
                rtb.Document = GetDocumentXaml(rtb)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.WriteLine("RichTextBoxHelper.RegisterIt: ex:" & ex.Message)
                rtb.Document = New FlowDocument()
            End Try
            AddHandler rtb.TextChanged, AddressOf TextChanged
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("RichTextBoxHelper: Unloaded control ignored:" & rtb.Name)
        End If
    End Sub

    ' When a RichTextBox Document changes, update the DependencyProperty so they're in sync.
    Private Shared Sub TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TextChangedEventArgs)
        Dim rtb As RichTextBox = TryCast(sender, RichTextBox)
        If rtb IsNot Nothing Then
            SetDocumentXaml(sender, rtb.Document)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys why bother with all the faff. This works perfectly. No code required

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="{Binding Mytextbinding}"/>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: In my case, it doesn't work without 'FlowDocument' tag.

Comment: `Text` property of `Run` is not dependency property so this does not even compile. Only dependency properties support binding like this.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: It won't work if you want to add multiple paragraphs or multiple runs to the rich text box.