# Rich Text box binding

Tags: c#

Hai All,
      I am in a problem while doing my new project in WPF using MVVM pattern.As you all know in MVVM all the datas in the entities are directly binding in the XAML in the presentation.In a normal text box we can bind the data by telling the path,but my problem is how can we bind data to a richtext box.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding)