# User control with richTextBox, bindable richTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I try make user control with richTextBox because I need bindable richTextbox.

I found some solution here: [Richtextbox wpf binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding).

I would like to use solution of **Arcturus**. Create user control with richTextBox control and use dependency property.

In XAML I have only richTextBox control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.BindableRichTextBoxControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox Name="RichTextBox" Grid.Row="0"/>    
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In CodeBehind:

```
public partial class BindableRichTextBoxControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Document", typeof(FlowDocument), typeof(BindableRichTextBoxControl), 
    new PropertyMetadata(OnDocumentChanged));

    public FlowDocument Document
    {
        get { return (FlowDocument)GetValue(DocumentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DocumentProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnDocumentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (BindableRichTextBoxControl)d;
        if (e.NewValue == null)
            control.RichTextBox.Document=new FlowDocument();

        //?
        control.RichTextBox.Document = document;
    }


    public BindableRichTextBoxControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I am little confuse with last line in OnDocumentChanged method.

```
        control.RichTextBox.Document = document;
```

I can’t identify what is varibale **document**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he means this:

```
private static void OnDocumentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBoxControl control = (RichTextBoxControl) d;
    if (e.NewValue == null)
        control.RTB.Document = new FlowDocument(); //Document is not amused by null :)
    else
        control.RTB.Document = e.NewValue;
}
```

but I recommend you leave a comment on his original answer.