# How to return formatted text from a method call in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, string-formatting

I'm developing a plugin interface and I would like to have one method that returns formatted text in a way that a WPF control can just show the plugin result. What would be the best way to return that text?

This way I will only need to assign the plugin result to a WPF text control (maybe a RichTextBox or something like that).

I would like to support bold, underline, etc ...

EDIT: Summarizing, I'm searching from a string "format" that allow 3rd party coders to return me a simple string with encoded format so I just need to do:

```
 myRichTextBox.Text = (IPlugin)3rdPartyPlugin.ExecutePlugin();
```

And the text appears formatted.

Comment: You need to save it as XML/HTML, check [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding

Comment: http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/09/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor

http://www.shawnduggan.com/?p=54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various Code behind ways to return a formatted text...

1] As Text

[WPF Flowdocument and Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx)

2] As a graphically rendered text ...

In any custom control's overriden OnRender() method you can graphically paint the formatted text as a drawing ...

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        this.formattedToolTip = new FormattedText(
                (string)this.TextProperty,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface(
                     new FontFamily("Arial"),
                     FontStyles.Normal,
                     FontWeights.Bold,
                     FontStretches.Normal),
                11,
                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black));

        drawingContext.DrawText(
                this.formattedToolTip,
                new Point(10, 10)); //// Margin of 10 pixels from top and left.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like FlowDocument is the way to go. Great!

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply go for `String`. RTF text can be happily represented as XML in any encoding you like IIRC.

Something tells me you aren't actually asking "how to return the text", but how to generate it? If so, please rephrase the question.