# Binding RichTextBox.Document and TextBlock.Inlines (not dependency properties)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I've got a `RichTextBox` and a `TextBlock` that are nested in a `DataTemplate`. I'm trying to bind them to a dynamic content, which includes hyperlinks and images (so I can't use the `Text` property).

How would I be able to bind those properties to the content?

Comment: You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding

Comment: All of the answers include `Dependency Object`. I actually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly bind to a property that isn't a `DependencyProperty`.

One workaround would be to subclass `RichTextBox` and add a `DependencyProperty`. You would implement your new property by setting the value of `RichTextBox.Document`.