# Binding RichTextBox to a string

Tags: wpf, xaml

This may be a very basic question for some but I am rather stuck and haven't been able to find a direct answer from stack or google. If anyone could help that would be great, Was wondering How do I bind a RichTextbox `Text` to a string.

So I have a variable on my MVVM called Notes and would like to bind it to the Radrichtextbox.

I was thinking something on the lines of this:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox1" Text="{Binding Notes}" />
```

But there's no Text Methods :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `RichTextBox`([link](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit)) from Extended WPF Toolkit.

Example:

```
<toolkit:RichTextBox x:Name="_richTextBox" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="10"
                      Text="{Binding Notes}" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

where `toolkit` is namespace to Extended WPF Toolkit library:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

*Installation guide:*

Instructions for using the Extended WPF Toolkit binaries ([link](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/106016)):

1. Install .NET Framework 4.0 or 4.5
2. Download the ExtendedWPFToolkit_Binaries
3. Right-click ExtendedWPFToolkit_Binaries.zip -> Properties -> Unblock
4. Unzip the ExtendedWPFToolkit_Binaries.zip
5. Add a using statement ("using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;") to the top of .cs files
6. Add a new xmlns (for example, xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit") to the top of XAML files
7. In your XAML, use the namespace prefix (in the above example, )

Or you can install this library by NuGet ([link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/extended.wpf.toolkit/)):

```
PM> Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit
```

Comment: @user3276954 are you sure that you using `RichTextBox` from http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: I added in the namespace, says richtextbox does not exist in "http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"

Comment: And I'm not sure, Im using default one from vs 2012

Comment: @user3276954 check my answer again.

Comment: THANKS BUD! was a great response

Comment: This toolkit is only free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah. Try this

```
    <RichTextBox>
        <RichTextBox.Document>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Notes}" />
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox.Document>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: This solution was also proposed by FakeCaleb here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468 - however as commented there, this will effectively give you a TextBox, removing most of the purpose of a RichTextBox

Answer (score 0):

We had a different Licence agreements to display in read only mode. So we implement a read only file binding. Not for editing, but for easily binding to a file on the file system and displaying it.

http://www.wpfsharp.com/2011/08/01/loading-a-richtextbox-from-an-rtf-file-using-binding-or-a-richtextfile-control

Answer (score -5):

I think what you want is

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox1" Text="{Binding Path=Notes}" />
```

Check it out here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090016

Comment: I did say there's no Text Method.

Comment: Why would you post this if you didn't test it? `RichTextBox` doesn't have a text property.