# Attached property not updating my view model

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I used the technique presented in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding) (Ray Burn's answer) to bind my `RichTextBox` to the underlying `string`-type property of my View Model (VM). The problem I'm facing is that the underlying field doesn't appear to be updating when user types something in the `RichTextBox`, even after focus changes. Here's the relevant XAML (`SyntaxHighlighterTextBox` is a custom control that inherits from `RichTextBox`):

```
<local:SyntaxHighlighterTextBox 
      local:RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml="{Binding Query, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Here is the `Query` property of the underlying VM:

```
Public Property Query() As String
  Get
    Return mQuery
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As String)
    mQuery = value
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Query"))
  End Set
End Property
```

### Edit

Here's my handler's code:

```
Public Shared Sub MyHandler(obj As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim rtb = DirectCast(obj, SyntaxHighlighterTextBox)

    Dim xaml = GetDocumentXaml(rtb)
    Dim doc = New FlowDocument()
    range = New TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd)

    range.Load(New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xaml)), DataFormats.Text)

    rtb.Document = doc

    AddHandler range.Changed, Sub(obj2, e2)
                                If rtb.Document Is doc Then
                                  Dim buffer As New MemoryStream()
                                  range.Save(buffer, DataFormats.Text)
                                  SetDocumentXaml(rtb, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray()))
                                End If
                              End Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to specify the Mode of the binding? Mode=OneWayToSource  or TwoWay in your case

Comment: @nkoniishvt: Yes, all of those. None does the trick.

Comment: post the code in DocumentXaml property and callback

Comment: @eranotzap: Added callback code.

Comment: So your type of the attached property is Document and your binding it to a String property is your ViewModel ?

Comment: @eranotzap: well...yes!?

Comment: do you get a Binding error ? or is the binding o'k with this ?

Comment: @eranotzap: I do not get any errors. It just simply doesn't update the underlying property. Neither does it invoke the call back function except for the first time at the startup. No exception is thrown in the first invocation.

Comment: That sounds ok than , it makes sense that's it's only called once . 
since the attached property does not know that the document was changed... 

in order to update the query string in your vm .

Comment: @eranotzap: But the call back does attach a handler to `range.Change` event which in turn calls SetDocumentXaml() function (which is a simple wrapper that calls attach property's `SetValue`. So in essance I *am* trying to intimate the change.

Comment: Is it ever called ? 
The document changed handler .

Comment: No, never. I suspected this could be due to the `range` object going out of scope and thus getting wiped by the GC, and therefore I upgraded it to class level, but even then it doesn't ever get called.