# WPF MVVM: Binding a RichTextBox document?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to refactor a method currently sat in code-behind to the view model. There is a btn click event which builds a `TextRange` from the `RichTextBox` Rtf & then executes some text formatting:

```
 private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRange rangeOfText = new TextRange(richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentStart, richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentEnd);

        if (richTextBoxArticleBody.Text.Contains("trowd"))
        {
            blah blah
```

I have tried to use this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding/) answer to use a deependency object to bind the document to a string property in the view model:

Dependency Property class:

```
public class RichTextBoxHelper : DependencyObject
{
    private static HashSet<Thread> _recursionProtection = new HashSet<Thread>();

    public static string GetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(DocumentXamlProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDocumentXaml(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        _recursionProtection.Add(Thread.CurrentThread);
        obj.SetValue(DocumentXamlProperty, value);
        _recursionProtection.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentXamlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DocumentXaml",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(RichTextBoxHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            "",
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            (obj, e) =>
            {
                if (_recursionProtection.Contains(Thread.CurrentThread))
                    return;

                var richTextBox = (RichTextBox)obj;

                // Parse the XAML to a document (or use XamlReader.Parse())

                try
                {
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetDocumentXaml(richTextBox)));
                    var doc = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(stream);

                    // Set the document
                    richTextBox.Document = doc;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    richTextBox.Document = new FlowDocument();
                }

                // When the document changes update the source
                richTextBox.TextChanged += (obj2, e2) =>
                {
                    RichTextBox richTextBox2 = obj2 as RichTextBox;
                    if (richTextBox2 != null)
                    {
                        SetDocumentXaml(richTextBox, XamlWriter.Save(richTextBox2.Document));
                    }
                };
            }
        )
    );
}
```

I am then binding my view to a string property in the viewModel like so:

```
cntrls:RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml="{Binding RichTextBoxBody, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

ViewModel Property:

```
private string _RichTextBoxBody;
    public string RichTextBoxBody
    {
        get { return _RichTextBoxBody; }
        set
        {
            _RichTextBoxBody = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RichTextBoxBody");
        }
    }
```

The string is successfully passed into the view model. Finally, here is my view model button command method. I'm getting stuck here as I can't get the string value into a `TextRange`:

```
 private void FormatCommandAction()
    {

        TextRange rangeOfText = new TextRange(RichTextBoxBody.ContentStart, RichTextBoxBody.ContentEnd);

         if (ModelviewArticle.ArticleBody.Contains("trowd"))
        {
            blah blah
```

Is this worth pursuing or even possible, I really want rid of the code-behind if I can...

Comment: Your question seems slightly misleading. You could rephrase the question to `How do I construct a TextRange from a string in a VM?`. If you look at it that way, you can maybe question "do I even want a TextRange or should I look at the purpose of the existing function and achieve my requirement without one". `TextRange` seems quite coupled to UI elements, so if you absolutely have to use one, why not have this entire functionality in a Behavior and keep your VM clean?

Comment: Fair point. I may have to keep this in the code behind as I need to take the RTB document, format the text (no bold, size 10 Arial etc.) & rebind it with the view. Can't see a clean way of doing this outside of the code-behind. Extended WPF toolkit offer a TextFormatter interface but I can't get it to return formatted text.

Comment: `format the text (no bold, size 10 Arial etc.)` <- All of which are UI concerns :) so it rightfully should be kept out of the VM and something like a Behavior would be ideal for such tasks.

Comment: Yeah I suppose you're right. Just don't like having button click events in the code-behind unless absolutely necessary.