# how to bind observable list to richtextbox in WPf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am have one application in WPF which has one Richtextbox .
there are two classes from which I want to gather the data and display in richtextbox. I am using Observable list to bind the data to Richtext box but its giving me exception.

Exception:Caught: "Failed to create a 'DependencyProperty' from the text 'Background'." (System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException)
A System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException was caught: "Failed to create a 'DependencyProperty' from the text 'Background'."

Code :
 result.DataContext = HttpGetSender.tcp_trace;

tcp_trace is the observable list

Comment: <RichTextBox Name="result"  IsDocumentEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="474" Margin="10,252.8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="687" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="5">

Comment: I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding this as well

Comment: No luck though . not sure if we need to do any change in the xaml

Comment: Please edit your question. Do not post code or XAML in comments. It's unreadable. Also add the code where you actually "bind the data" to the RichTextBox.

Comment: I have edited the question and added line where I am adding observable list as dataconext to rich textbox

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You would have to set the RichTextBox's [Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document(v=vs.110).aspx) property to an instance of a FlowDocument. Please read the online documentation on MSDN.