# Is it possible to bind an ObservableCollection to a richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF desktop app.

I am using the RTF control.

I want to bind this control to an observablecollection.

This model will have (for instance) these properties:

```
string name
image  Logo
Brush  MyColor
```

So my intent is to display the name, image and background color for each record.

Can it be done?

At present I just have code behind that does all this but I am just adding to the blocks/paragrapgh ~

```
rtb.Document.Blocks.Add(para);
```

etc

view:

```
 <RichTextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="rtb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="88,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="341">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>

            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to use a RichTextBox instead of a regular ItemsControl with a custom template for your items?

Comment: Hi, I originally used a list box and used a datatemplate. It all worked well but the scrolling was a bit 'jumpy'  I was hoping to use a smoother look and feel using the rtb..

Comment: The listbox is jumpy because the scrollbar controls indexed positions into your collection.  If you use an ItemsControl wrapped by a ScrollViewer instead then you can achieve the smooth scrolling that you want.

Comment: @RogerN Hi, thanks for that tip. I shall give it a go - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The RichTextBox isn't an ItemsControl that supports binding to an `IEnumerable`.

You could possibly create a behaviour that lets you bind to a document as suggested here:

[Richtextbox wpf binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding)

But if you want to display something from an `ObservableCollection` in a RichTextBox I think the simplest approach would be to iterate through the collection and add blocks to the RichTextBox programmatically. As mentioned, it doesn't support data binding out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks. It is what I thought I shall leave this question open for the remainder of the day before accepting just in case there is a work-around from someone. ta

Comment: Could probably rig something up using an `IValueConverter` too, but I doubt it would be very useful.