# Binding a collection of strings to a FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, flowdocument

I am adapting an older WPF application that we use as a build tool on my team. One component is a LoggingWindow class that contains a FlowDocument that we pass build log text to via an MSBuild ILogger. The document typically ends up being over 1000 pages long by the time the build is complete, receiving over 100k lines of log text as the build proceeds. Because of the sheer mass of text being passed, it does not perform very well. This is how we handle this now:

This is the XAML for the LoggingWindow class:

```
<FlowDocumentPageViewer Name="LogPageViewer" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <FlowDocument Name="LogDocument" ColumnWidth="800" Foreground="LightGray" Background="Black" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Consolas" TextAlignment="Left">
        <FlowDocument.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </FlowDocument.Resources>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentPageViewer>
```

We spin up a task that polls a ConcurrentQueue for messages. As you can see, I have no idea how to performantly add messages to the document, so I grab messages in batches of 10 and sleep for 10 ms if there were messages, and sleep for 100 ms if there weren't, in an attempt to not block the main thread too much.

```
public void Start()
{
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _uiProcessor = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateUi(_cts.Token));
}

private void UpdateUi(CancellationToken context)
{
    while (!context.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (_messageQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            var count = Math.Min(_messageQueue.Count, 10);
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                LogMessage message;
                _messageQueue.TryDequeue(out message);
                AddText(message);
            }
            // there are likely to be more messages, so only sleep for 10 ms
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        else
        {
            // there aren't likely to be more messages yet, so we can sleep for 100 ms
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

The AddText method must run on the main thread because that's the thread that owns the FlowDocument, so we need to check the Dispatcher before adding a paragraph.

```
private void AddText(LogMessage message)
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        try
        {
            var timestampText = $"{message.Timestamp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")}:{new string(' ', message.Indent * 2)}";
            var span = new Span
            {
                FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas"),
                FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal,
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal,
                FontStretch = FontStretches.Normal,
                FontSize = 12,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0xd3, 0xd3, 0xd3))
            };
            span.Inlines.Add(new Run(timestampText) { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) });
            span.Inlines.Add(new Run(message.Message) { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(message.Color), FontWeight = message.Weight });
            var paragraph = new Paragraph(span);

            LogDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

            if (AutoScrollMenuItem.IsChecked)
            {
                LogPageViewer.LastPage();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorIndex++;
            using (var fs = File.OpenWrite($"FormatError-{_errorIndex:00}.txt"))
            {
                var sw = new StreamWriter(fs)
                {
                    AutoFlush = true
                };

                sw.WriteLine("Error: ");
                sw.WriteLine(ex);
                sw.WriteLine();

                sw.Write(message.Message);
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<LogMessage>(AddText), message);
    }
}
```

I would like to refactor this to a solution that makes use of WPF data binding, so that I can add a LogMessage to an ObservableCollection and defer the actual UI updates to WPF, which will probably handle it better than I can manually. However, I am new to WPF and even newer to binding, so I'm not really sure how I would go about doing this.

Also, if anyone has any better suggestion as to how to performantly do what I'm trying to do, that would be great. My goal is to be able to keep up with the pace of log messages being added as much as possible while not blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

`WPF RichTextBox` does not support `Binding` to an `IEnumerable`; however, if you are working with plain text, you might not need one. Instead, you can use an `ItemsControl`, with a `TextBlock` as its `ItemTemplate`, and a `VirtualizingStackPanel` as its `ItemsPanel`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

You can easily bind this to an ObservableCollection of string (Messages). While you can easily enumerate the observable collection and get the whole text, *it has limited capabilities regarding text selection, Copy&Paste and etc.*

Apart from this, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641774/5615980), it seems that you can create an attached DocumentXaml (or DocumentRTF) property which will allow you to bind the `RichTextBox`'s document.