# Load files into different RichTextBoxes in TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

I have a following problem:

I have a `TabControl` with it's `ItemsSource` set to a Binding with an `ObservableCollection` object. Inside the `Content` property of `TabControl` I put a RichTextBox, to which I want to load a text file. Here is the XAML snippet:

```
        <TabControl Grid.Column="0" x:Name="openFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding OpenedFiles}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- this is the header template-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RichTextBox x:Name="fileTextBox"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

With each new file, I want to be able to load the contents of the file to the RichTextBox using `TextRange` and `FileStream` objects like so:

```
if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK )
{             
  TextRange range;
  System.IO.FileStream fStream;

  if (System.IO.File.Exists(openFile1.FileName))
  {
      range = new TextRange(RichTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
      fStream = new System.IO.FileStream(openFile1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
      range.Load(fStream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf );

      fStream.Close();
  }
}
```

However, I don't know how to reference the `RichTextBox` in the `ContentTemplate` from code-behind level.

Comment: would you mind to post how OpenedFiles items look like?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. OpenedFiles is an `ObservableColletion<OpenFile>` object, where `OpenFile` is a class that contains the files' path, stream etc.

I kinda figured out a workaround. I created a `MyTabItem` class that derives from standard `TabItem`. This class puts a `RichTextBox` as it's `Content` in the constructor, so that I can populate it in code-behind. But I don't like that solution. I think it's ugly and there must be a better way. Sorry if that's a noob question - I am just learning this for my uni course and want to learn good practices, not flaky workarounds.

Comment: Have a look at the solution posted here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding)