# Bind string to WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a `RichTextBox` and I want to bind it to the `string`. I have done some search but I have only found binding to the document, not to string.
At first I have tried this:

```
    <RichTextBox Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="5" 
                 BorderBrush="LightGray"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 Grid.RowSpan="11">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

But, it doesn't work and I understand why.

I think It will be solved by concatenating all paragraphs in this control, but I don't know how do this.

**Edit**

this is `Description` property:

```
private string _description;
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set
            {
                _description = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Description);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: "But, it doesn't work and I understand why" could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Binding works only on first line. When I press enter and I go on the second line Descritpion property doesn't changes anymore..

Comment: What does your `Description` property look like?

Comment: I edited my question..

Comment: The extended WPF toolkit (https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit) has this functionality. If you don't wan't to use this there is a SO answer to a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641774/9363973

Comment: @MindSwipe I have seen it, but it isn't binding with string...

Comment: I would think you'd need a converter for this, as the plain `String` is not an RTF-formatted one.  RTF text is not just  string.