# C# WPF How to transfer text from richtexbox to another richtexbox using button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in C# and I've got some issues with transferring text in WPF. I want that when I paste code into the first richtexbox, it will obfuscate by using button and shows in the second richtexbox but in first rtb it should be not changed.

Here is my code:

```
private void ButtonClicked2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string keyword = "class";
        string newString = obfuscateString;
        TextRange text = new TextRange(_richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, _richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        TextPointer current = text.Start.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        while (current != null)
        {
            string textInRun = current.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textInRun))
            {
                int index = textInRun.IndexOf(keyword);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    TextPointer selectionStart = current.GetPositionAtOffset(index, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    TextPointer selectionEnd = selectionStart.GetPositionAtOffset(keyword.Length, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    TextRange selection = new TextRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
                    selection.Text = newString;
                    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
                    _richTextBox.Selection.Select(selection.Start, selection.End);
                    _richTextBox.Focus();
                }
            }
            current = current.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: It is helpful if you describe what the behavior is of the existing code. *How* is it not working?

Comment: The reason you cant tell us which line isn't working the way you expect it, is because you haven't debugged it. please do so, and be more specific about the line that you think is having the problems, why you think that, and what you expect

Comment: It's working but its only show in first RTB. I don't know how to transfer code to another RTB without changing paste code in first RTB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In would not do this in CodeBehind, it is simple with Binding. So define a ViewModel where you define the OriginalText and ModifyedText as Property and a Command for the Transformation in case the Button is clicked.

So this can be like:

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _originalText = "My Original Text";
    private String _modifyedText = "Place for Obfuscatet Text";

    public String OriginalText
    {
        get => _originalText;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _originalText)) return;
            _originalText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String ModifyedText
    {
        get => _modifyedText;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _modifyedText)) return;
            _modifyedText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand Obfuscate { get; set; }

    public GuestViewModel()
    {
        Obfuscate = new RelayCommand(DoObfuscate, o => true);
    }

    private void DoObfuscate(object obj)
    {
        ModifyedText = DoModify(OriginalText);
    }

    //Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged and DoModify etc...
}
```

Now bind the String properties to the two RichTextBoxes (there are multiple option for doing this see [Richtextbox wpf binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding)) and the Button to the Command.

Xaml may be like:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding TODO}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RichTextBox Grid.Row="0">
         <FlowDocument PageHeight="180">
             <Paragraph>
                 <Run Text="{Binding OriginalText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
             </Paragraph>
         </FlowDocument>
     </RichTextBox>
     <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Process Text" Command="{Binding Obfuscate}"></Button>
     <RichTextBox Grid.Row="2">
         <FlowDocument PageHeight="180">
             <Paragraph>
                 <Run Text="{Binding ModifyedText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
             </Paragraph>
         </FlowDocument>
     </RichTextBox>
 </Grid>
```

More Information about bindings can be found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2012/10/12/xaml-binding-basics-101/