# Textbox doesn't fit to its content size in an expander

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I have a Xaml view where I'm trying to display Textbox inside a grid which is inside an Exander.

```
<Expander DataContext="{Binding DiagnosticCategories[0].DiagnosticResults[0]}" <!-- For the test -->
          Background="Transparent"
          Foreground="{StaticResource ActiveForegroundBrush}"
          IsExpanded="False">

                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBox
                            Margin="10"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            FontSize="13"
                            FontWeight="Light"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource ActiveForegroundBrush}"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Opacity="0.8"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                            SelectionBrush="Black"
                            Text="{Binding FormatedParameters, Mode=OneWay}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    [...]  
                </Grid>
            </Expander>
```

However, there is a problem with the Textbox which has a anormal height even if my text is just "aa"...

First, I thought that the problem was with the Grid.Row and the Textbox only fit it so I tried to add a StackPanel which doesn't fit the Grid.Row but it doesn't work. It seems that the problem is in the textbox.

With a TextBlock, I don't have this problem but I need the Textbox to display my text.

Comment: Please reduce your code sample to a minimum. If it already is, then provide the model classes you are binding to. I run your code (replaced the binding with the word 'test') and cannot find anything special with the height of the textbox. It looks exacty like the TextBlock.

Comment: can you also put a screenshot ? I did not understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `RichTextBox`.

When I want to use `TextBox`, I have the same problem under a certain height. I solved the problem by using `RichTextBox` instead of `TextBox`.

```
<Expander DataContext="{Binding DiagnosticCategories[0].DiagnosticResults[0]}" <!-- For the test -->
          Background="Transparent"
          Foreground="{StaticResource ActiveForegroundBrush}"
          IsExpanded="False">

                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <RichTextBox
                            Margin="10"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            FontSize="13"
                            FontWeight="Light"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource ActiveForegroundBrush}"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Opacity="0.8"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                            SelectionBrush="Black"
                            Text="{Binding FormatedParameters, Mode=OneWay}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    [...]  
                </Grid>
            </Expander>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, the basic RichTextBox control hasn't the property "Text" so I cannot bind my property as you said. Maybe you confuse with the control from Wpf Toolkit but I didn't use this librairy

Comment: No. RichTextBox is not Toolkit. Maybe this can work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, I'm a little unsure what you are trying to achieve. I added a couple of horizontal and vertical layouts to your example:

```
<Expander DataContext="{Binding DiagnosticCategories[0].DiagnosticResults[0]}"
        Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="200"
        IsExpanded="False">

    <Grid Margin="10" Background="Blue">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBox
                        Margin="10"
                        Background="Orange"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        FontSize="13"
                        FontWeight="Light"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        Opacity="0.8"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        SelectionBrush="Black"
                        Text="Test Text"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

And I get the following:

Closed:

[image]

Open:

[image]