# Making specific part of Text bold in RichTextBox in a DataGrid using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, format, richtextbox

I'm making a C# WPF application and currently have a DataGrid that contains various elements including a RichTextBox so that users can edit the text. However I would like to also give the option of making specific parts of the Text contained in the RichTextBox bold. This should be done by selecting part of the Text in a TextBox and pressing a button, that would make the selected text bold.

[So the highlighted "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" would be made bold when the button is pressed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxkfs.png)

My XAML is setup like this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DescriptionGrid"
      RowHeaderWidth="15"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Descriptions}"
      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description" Width="300">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RichTextBox Width="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True">
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding desc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I have not included every column, but it should give a understanding of what I'm working with.

So far I've managed to get the highlighted text. I then tried to add various bold tags around the selected text, however these tags just show up in the textbox.

Comment: You may bind the Document property with the help of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/345275/1136211

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> However I would like to also give the option of making specific parts of the Text contained in the RichTextBox bold. This should be done by selecting part of the Text in a TextBox and pressing a button, that would make the selected text bold

There are a few ways this can be accomplished. Currently it appears you are following `mvvm` with binding, this is the preferred way when working with `wpf`. With this in mind, you could create a new class that inherits the `RichTextBox` and implement the behavior you are needing.

Here's an example class that does just what you need:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace ChangeFontSelectionGridWPF
{
    public class RichTextSelection : RichTextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DoBoldSelectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                                                                    "DoBoldSelection", typeof(bool),
                                                                                                    typeof(RichTextSelection),
                                                                                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnBoldSelectionChanged))
                                                                                                    );

        public bool DoBoldSelection
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(DoBoldSelectionProperty);
            set => SetValue(DoBoldSelectionProperty, value);
        }

        public RichTextSelection()
            : base()
        {
        }

        private static void OnBoldSelectionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RichTextSelection rchTextSel = (RichTextSelection)d;
            if (rchTextSel.Selection != null)
                rchTextSel.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
        }
    }
}
```

After you recompile, you then can add this as your `DataTemplate` for that column, something like:

```
<DataTemplate>
             <local:RichTextSelection Width="Auto"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 DoBoldSelection="{Binding AllowBoldHighlight}"
                                                     >
                                <FlowDocument>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding desc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </FlowDocument>
                            </local:RichTextSelection>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

You'll notice a dependency property: `DoBoldSelection`. This property handles changing the font weight of the selected text. In the example above, that property is bound to a property in my `List<DescriptionObject>` which is `AllowBoldHighlight`.

My `DescriptionObject` class looks like:

```
public class DescriptionObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string desc { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        private bool allowHighlight = false;
        public bool AllowBoldHighlight
        {
            get => allowHighlight;
            set => SetProperty(ref allowHighlight, value);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value)) return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propName);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

`MainWindow.xaml` looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="ChangeFontSelectionGridWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChangeFontSelectionGridWPF"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="10"
                Click="Button_Click"
                Content="Bold"
                />
        <DataGrid x:Name="DescriptionGrid"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Descriptions}"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="300" Header="Description">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:RichTextSelection Width="Auto"
                                                     AcceptsReturn="True"
                                                     DoBoldSelection="{Binding AllowBoldHighlight}"
                                                     >
                                <FlowDocument>
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding desc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </FlowDocument>
                            </local:RichTextSelection>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.cs` looks like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<DescriptionObject> Descriptions { get; set; } = new List<DescriptionObject>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Descriptions.Add(new DescriptionObject() { desc = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" });
            Descriptions.Add(new DescriptionObject() { desc = "rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" });
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DescriptionGrid.SelectedItem is DescriptionObject dobj)
            {
                dobj.AllowBoldHighlight = true;
                dobj.AllowBoldHighlight = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

You'll notice that in `Button_Click` is where you could handle changing the `FontWeight` of selected text; basic example. The main driver for this is `dobj.AllowBoldHighlight = true`. What's happening is when you select/highlight text and then click on the button, `dobj.AllowBoldHighlight` property get's change which the fires off the `OnBoldSelectionChanged` in the `RichTextSelection` class. The example above gives you flexibility to turn it off and on per object/instance in your grid.

Here's a short clip of it working:

[image]

Hopefully this helps and addresses your concern, if any issues please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. This definitely solves to problem of formatting bold text in the RichTextBox. However, with this solution I ran into a new problem. If part of the string is made bold, then when I later try to get the string from the object, part of it is missing. So if I had the string "one two three four" and I made "three" bold. Then when trying to get the string I would only get "one two".
For now my solution is to store the TextRange from SelectionChanged and then using ApplyPropertyValue and afterwards overriding the string with itself from a local variable.