# RichTextBox setting bound property as a blank string when text is pasted into it

Tags: c#, xaml, richtextbox

I'm having a problem with one of the RichTextBox's in a program I'm working on right now.

If I type into the box everything works as it should and the bound property is updated with the text that is typed.

If a user, however, pastes any text into the RichTextBox from anywhere (inside or outside the program) the bound property is loaded with a blank string and, the failsafe's I have in place to catch that, fire and don't allow the user to save the updated information.

Even if I type into the box after I've pasted into it, the string remains empty. I can't figure out what's going on.

I included my binding below. I don't believe the code that updates the value in the database is the issue so I will not include it for now.

```
<RichTextBox
   x:Name="DescriptionBox"
   Padding="3"
   FontSize="14"
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <FlowDocument>
         <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="{Binding SelectedReference.Description}" />
         </Paragraph>
      </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

I don't believe the problem is with my binding as the text is updated when the user manually changes text in the box. The problem only occurs when the user pastes text into the box.

Comment: This one is a touch cookie. I will try to keep working on it later. But I can aid a bit: When pasting into the FlowDocument I'm sure that it is creating a new Block in the [FlowDocuments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) BlockCollection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Richtextbox wpf binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343468/richtextbox-wpf-binding)

Comment: @user9938, I believe my bindings are fine, the problem only happens when i paste into the RichTextBox

Comment: @Jon: Your binding as it is defined will work only for the one `Run` where it's defined. But when user add some another content (by using _paste_ command) a new block or `Run` inside the current block will be created, to which your `Binding` will not be applied.

Comment: @Jackdaw, Thanks for the advice. I'll give user9938's solution a try and close the question if it works.